# How does Grunt resolve file locations?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm looking at a [sample Angular App.](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app)

In the `index.html` file, there is a line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/<%= grunt.config.get('pkg.name') %>.js"></script>
```

I'm not familiar with Grunt, and at the moment don't have time to study it. Would someone briefly explain how Grunt resolves the file name, and how the file name is set, changed, stored, etc?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Grunt documentation:

> Note: all file paths are relative to the Gruntfile unless the current
>   working directory is changed with grunt.file.setBase or the --base
>   command-line option.

I am afraid that there is no substitute for studying Grunt. The sample Gruntfile page is most helpful, but you need to read it carefully, and probably go back and refer to it often.

http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile

The string 'pkg' is a convention that is used in the Gruntfile.js file. Reading the Gruntfile.js file and the package.json file you should be able to find where paths are configured.